# How to get small source photo from facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get Facebook source small photo from a photo's fbid to show it in my site.To do that i have used this query-

```
'https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+src_small+FROM+photo+WHERE+object_id='.$id
```

But some user of my site reported me that some of their photos are not showing in my site.When i checked they was right.Some ID's returns blank photo.I tried a lot to fix the problem but failed.I just can't understand why it's happened.Is there some thing wrong with my FB app.

Now my question is that, what i need to do if i want to get **src_small** photo every time  with any photo id?

Comment: Could you please provide one example object id which returns blank photo?

Comment: Some of failed Object_IDs are - **236118939928010,1375815606036334,1379876878966670,668003249909426**

Answer (score 0):

You can observe the behavior via user_ID/ablums API endpoint.

For Graph API v1.0, if user A is friend of user B, then user A can get user B albums/photos if user A authorized the app with **friends_photos** permission scope:

[image]

But since Graph API v1.0 has been deprecated, so this doesn't work anymore because all **friends_*** permissions have been removed in Graph API v2.0.

But you still have the way to request albums/photos in Graph API v2.0, if the user B authorized with **user_photos** permission, then every user with basic info permission in the **same app** can call 
**USER_B_ID/albums** to get user B's ablums.

[image]

In other words, the API call to photo object ID example you give is failed because **the owner of this photo object ID** may not authorize your app with "user_photos" permission.

I'm not sure this is the main reason for your case, but it's one of the reason if you cannot get the photos.

Comment: I am sorry bro,your answer didn't helped me.I am still in that problem.

Comment: So, are you sure that the owner of 236118939928010 (Taslima Jaahan) already authorized your app with user_photos permission? If that's the case you should file a bug report at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: I agree.  I could not retrieve any of the properties of any of the objects with the IDs you mentioned above.  More information on photo permissions from the api docs:
   
"To read the photo table you need any valid access_token if it is public and owned by the Page.
user_photos permissions to access photos and albums uploaded by the user, and photos in which the user has been tagged.
friends_photos permissions to access friends' photos and photos in which the user's friends have been tagged."